# How can I make my stroke stay inside the corner in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

My stroke seems to be getting out from the edge of my illustration.

I have looked in both the stroke panel and anchor points, but I can't seem to find a solution.

[image: Screenshot of stroke extending beyond illustration boundary]

I just want the stroke to stay inside, and not go outside the line.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called a *clipping mask*. Just copy the object you want to mask in front of the object(s) you want to clip. Select the objects and clip mask and choose **Edit → Clipping Mask → Make**.

The alternative is to expand the stroke and shape it so it's inside your box. But I would stick with clipping masks in this case.

Comment: Does not work, because i am basically using the same object and therefore it makes the strokes go outside once more.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. Maybe you missed a step? I encourage you to try again.